# Run command line process from Java synchronously

Tags: java, aws-lambda

I am running a command-line program (ClamAV virus scanner) from Java as below. I need to run it synchronously since it's running in AWS Lambda and if it goes async, the lambda will terminate early. It seems "many" times it comes out without completing. What is the best way to fix this? I added ugly Thread. Sleep improved the situation a little. I actually don't mind going that route but need to find the exact place where it should sleep. Please help!

```
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process proc = rt.exec(command);
    BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
    BufferedReader errorReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));
    String line;
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    int exitValue = proc.waitFor();
    logger.info("Exit Value:" + exitValue);
    while ((line = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {
        out.append("\n").append(line);
    }
    if (exitValue != 0) {
        while ((line = errorReader.readLine()) != null) {
            out.append("\n").append(line);
            logger.error(line);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The call to waitFor should not return until the process has terminated. What it the command you are running? Perhaps the command itself (clamav) forks and returns? If so there is nothing wrong with the Java code as such. And what is the output you get when you run this?

Comment: in most cases I do get complete output of clamscan (the command). but sometimes it returns without the output. the output is stdout from the process.

Comment: You cannot reliably read the output (or error) of a process that has terminated.  Call `proc.waitFor()` *after* you have read the streams.

Answer (score 0):

The method [exec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)) executes in a different process as stated by the javadoc:

> Executes the specified string command in a **separate process.**

What you can do is put the main thread in a wait state until you know that the separated thread has completed his task. You can do that using the method [waitFor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor--) of the Process class:

> Causes the current thread to wait, if necessary, until the process represented by this Process object has terminated

Comment: Is it possible that the watiFor does wait till the process is completed but it takes couple of seconds to gather the output of process? This is just my guess. if I do waitFor() with 5 seconds, will it wait for 5 seconds regardless or will it come out as soon as it has the exit signal?

Comment: Be sure to flush the streams. May be that simply the streams are not flushed.

Comment: you mean inputReader.close() and errorReader.close() ? Also is proc.destroy() do anything or is needed? Thank you!

Comment: I just want to confirm before trying this out. proc.destroy() is actually giving error in some cases probably because its already closed?